# Is Marissa Faireborn related to Flint?

Tags: transformers, gi-joe

In the G1 Transformers cartoon, we meet Marissa Faireborn, a member of the Earth Defense Command. We learn that she has family in the military.

Both the Transformers and GI Joe are made by Hasbro, and both TV shows were made by the same animation studios.

Marissa Faireborn shares a last name with Dashiell Faireborn, aka Flint, one of the members of GI Joe. Flint is often depicted as having a romantic relationship with Lady Jaye, another member of the team.

Has there been any official statement linking the characters?

Comment: Probably, and yet somehow not quite officially? http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Marissa_Faireborn#Notes

Comment: "*Although Marissa's father has long been accepted to be the G.I. Joe member Flint...there were no statements as to the identity of her mother until recently. ... former Transformers writer and story editor Flint Dille confirmed fellow G.I. Joe member Lady Jaye as Marissa's mother. This would subsequently make Marissa a distant relative of Destro as well. However, in an interview with G. I. Joe fansite Joe Headquarters, Dille added the caveat that "I've always thought of Flint as being too young to have a daughter that old."*-http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Marissa_Faireborn#Notes

Answer (score 1):

In the original cartoon, it's strongly implied and generally taken to be so - although it's never *officially* stated that she's his daughter.

In IDW continuity, however, it *is* clearly canonically confirmed that Marissa is Flint's daughter and this is something repeatedly broached - albeit, she's one he never knew about until she was already an adult, her being the result of a relationship with a college girlfriend named Claire Austin, when he was young.

Marissa as a result only actually later on taking on her father's last name and only at that, to spite her very estranged and alcoholic mother.

[image]